# click event not triggering for input type checkbox in angular 7

Tags: angular

Click or change event not triggering when i click on input type checkbox

Html code:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let category of facet.value">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{facet.value[0].DisplayFacetName}}"
         [(ngModel)]="check" (click)="test($event)">
      <label for="{{category.Title}}">{{ category.Title }}</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Component code:

```js
test(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

click event not triggering, there is no error any help?

Comment: Could you provide more context about your component?

Answer (score 0):

Your input element only provides `(change)` and `(input)` events, no `(click)` events.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Using change instead of click should work

```
(change)="test($event)"
```

Comment: No it is supporting `click` event, according your link: "In addition to the common attributes shared by all <input> elements, "checkbox" inputs support the following attributes".

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve click functionality with the event handler.

```
 <input  type="checkbox" name="{{facet.value[0].DisplayFacetName}}"
     [(ngModel)]="check" (ngModelChange)="test($event)"> Checkbox

<button (click)="test($event)">Change </button>  



   test(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```